# Pandas - plot P1D time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, plot, timestamp

how can i plot this `data` with panda and include the `date` for every value?

```json
p1d = {
  "times": "2021-05-15/P1D",
  "start": "2021-05-16T00:00:00",
  "end": "2021-05-21T00:00:00",
  "data": [
    [1, 1.2141],
    [2, 1.2152],
    [3, 1.2225],
    [4, 1.2177],
    [5, 1.223],
    [6, 1.218]
  ],
  "type": "time"
}
```

its possible to use this plot:

```py
df_p1d = pd.DataFrame(p1d['data'], columns=["date", "value"])
df_p1d.plot(x="date", y="value")
```

but it does not have any dates like:

```py
2021-05-16T00:00:00
2021-05-17T00:00:00
2021-05-18T00:00:00
2021-05-19T00:00:00
2021-05-20T00:00:00
2021-05-21T00:00:00
```

[image]

Comment: You need to change the dtype of your date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df_p1d = pd.DataFrame(p1d['data'], columns=["date", "value"])
df_p1d["date2"] = pd.date_range(p1d["start"], p1d["end"], periods=len(p1d["data"]))
ax = df_p1d.plot(x="date2", y="value")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

[image: Change major formatter]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

p1d = {
  "times": "2021-05-15/P1D",
  "start": "2021-05-16T00:00:00",
  "end": "2021-05-21T00:00:00",
  "data": [
    [1, 1.2141],
    [2, 1.2152],
    [3, 1.2225],
    [4, 1.2177],
    [5, 1.223],
    [6, 1.218]
  ],
  "type": "time"
}

df_p1d = pd.DataFrame(p1d['data'], columns=["date", "value"])
df_p1d["X_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(p1d['start'],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') 

for i in range(len(df_p1d)):
    df_p1d.at[i,"X_DATE"] += timedelta(days=i)

print(df_p1d)
```

Output:

```
   date   value     X_DATE
0     1  1.2141 2021-05-16
1     2  1.2152 2021-05-17
2     3  1.2225 2021-05-18
3     4  1.2177 2021-05-19
4     5  1.2230 2021-05-20
5     6  1.2180 2021-05-21
```